# Using Python's subprocess.call() as platform independent

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I am using Python's subprocess.call() to invoke few executables written in C++. For example:

```
subprocess.call(['<executable>'])
```

While the above works in Linux without any issues, how do I make it to work in Windows or make it platform independent? The executable are made to work in both Linux as well as in Windows.

I do not want to use shell=true as it could be a security issue.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? The `subprocess` module also works on Windows.

Comment: Yes, I don't see a problem with that. For copying files, a better option might be [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree).

Comment: you can pass parameters as the second argument to subprocess.call

Comment: I think the problem is if I want to invoke some windows specific commands using subprocess. Say, I want to copy a directory in Windows, can I use: subprocess.call(['xcopy', 'dir1', 'dir2']). Here I am just copying the entire directory (dir1) and copying back with the name dir2. Note that I do not have Windows machine to test this out, hence I am asking the question

Comment: If you don't have a Windows machine available, then definitely use `shutil.copytree`, which is more likely to work than any manual calling of `xcopy`. But you'll have to eventually test your code on a Windows machine if you want it to work there.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I will.

Comment: Thanks @greg-hewgill. `shutil` module is the right way to go, which will make platform independent. As you suggested, I have used `shutil.copytree` for copying the entire directory. For others who come across this question, `shutil.rmtree` removes the entire directory and `shutil.copy2` copies contents or specific files in the directory.